# Fixing a Cross App Scripting Vulnerability - Android App

Tags: android-security

My App was removed from Play Store and I didn't understand the reason. Maybe is because of the webView I use.

I would like to understand if my code has any vulnerability. It is very specific code.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:hist.back();", null);
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:hist.back();");
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I can bet that one of the Google security scanners scanned your app and marked it as loading dynamically javascript into the webview which can be considered a vulnerability.